# How to Merge one git repository into another repository branch

Tags: github

I have one GIT repository branch is called xxx, and I have second GIT repository branch is called VVV.

I want to merge the xxx branch into vvv branch.
How can i achieve that ???

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout vvv
git merge xxx
```